# FindAll does not get all Child Objects in WPFListView using SilkTest 17.5

Tags: vb.net, automated-tests, silktest

I need to scroll to an element present in table for a WPF application, the value is dynamically provided during run time.

I have below code which runs fine for small listview  as scrollbar moves correctly but does not scroll to elements near the end of a long list.

My list is as below and I scroll using names (`A1`, `A2`, ...)

```
A1   1   3  

A2   1   5

S1   1   3  

Q2   1   5

.....

.....

Z7   1   3  

Z82   1   5

Z9   1   3  

Imports SilkTest.Ntf.Wpf
Public Module Main
  Dim _desktop As Desktop = Agent.Desktop

  Public Sub Main()
    Dim iPosition As Double = 0.5
    Dim iSumPosition As Double = 0.0
    Dim sObjlocator As String = "//WPFListView[@automationId='MyListView']"
    Dim sData As String = "Z118"
    Dim sObjSublocator As String = "//WPFToggleButton[@caption='*']"

    Dim rows As IList = _desktop.WPFListView(sObjlocator).FindAll(sObjSublocator)

    Dim sObjExist As Boolean = False
    For Each row As WPFToggleButton In rows
      Dim sString As String = row.Text
      Console.WriteLine(sString)     '  <--names
      If Trim(sString) = sData Then
        sObjExist = True
        Exit For
      Else
        iSumPosition += iPosition
        Console.WriteLine(iSumPosition)  ' <--Position

       _desktop.WPFListView(sObjlocator).ScrollToPosition(iSumPosition, Orientation.Vertical)
      End If 
    Next
  End Sub
End Module
```

**Issue:**

As shown in the output below, the printed lines `A1`, `A10`, ... from `Console.WriteLine(sString)` and the numbers from `Console.WriteLine(iSumPosition)`, works only for a few objects off-screen, the scrollbar moves vertically down, but if my list is large and I need scroll many times then scrolling doesn't work any more.

The scroll bar does not scroll to the end for names near the end of the list, only if my list is very small then it scrolls down to very last element as well.

In Debug mode I see that the rows list (`Dim rows As IList = _desktop.WPFListView(sObjlocator).FindAll(sObjSublocator)`) does not have the values (names) for elements near the end of the list.

In the output below, we can see names and positions are printed initially but near the end of the long list only positions are printed.

**Output:**

```
A1
0.5
A10
1
A11
1.5
A12
2

...

...

...

9.5

10

10.5
```

**Additional info:**

- Locator type is WPFScrollBar.
- WPF pre-fill forms settings in SilkTest is : yes
- Using automation testing tool : Microfocus SilkTest 17.5

Comment: Any one can help ?

Comment: Can you try sending page down keystrokes to the WPFListView instead of calling `ScrollToPosition`? Something like `WPFListView(sObjlocator).TypeKeys("<Page-Down>")`...

Comment: I will try this and let you know the results but I am not sure if this is the solution, as my scrollbar is moving down and but it does not move all the way down as elements in the list 'rows' in long list(size 80+ ) are emty/null.   I have tried one more thing. once first For-Next loop completes , I again run Dim rows2 As IList = _desktop.WPFListView(sObjlocator).FindAll(sObjSublocator) and then it moves completely to the end but now it does not stop at potion where I want it to stop.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a while loop to continually increase the scroll bar value (to scroll down) until the maximum scroll bar value is met. Below I have put together some sample code that demonstrates this when executed against the WPF sample application that ships with Silk Test.

```
Imports SilkTest.Ntf.Wpf
Public Module Main
Dim _desktop As Desktop = Agent.Desktop

Public Sub Main()

    With _desktop.WPFWindow("@caption='WPF Sample Application'")
        .SetActive()
        .WPFMenu().Select("/Controls/Basic Controls")
    End With

    With _desktop.WPFWindow("@caption='Basic Controls'")
        .WPFTabControl("@automationId='tabControl'").Select("ScrollBar")
        Dim sScrollBar As WPFScrollBar
        sScrollBar = .WPFScrollBar("//WPFTabControl[@automationId='tabControl']/WPFScrollBar[2]")
        'Set the scroll bar to the top
        sScrollBar.SetValue(0.0)

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)

        Dim iPosition As Double
        iPosition = 0.0

        While sScrollBar.Value < sScrollBar.Maximum
            Console.WriteLine("scroll Bar Maximum  " + sScrollBar.Maximum.ToString)
            Console.WriteLine("scroll Bar Value  " + sScrollBar.Value.ToString)

            'Set Scroll bar position
            sScrollBar.SetValue(iPosition)
            'Return text within scroll          
            Console.WriteLine(.WPFTextBox("@automationId='txtScrollBarEvents'").Text)
            'Increment scroll bar position for each iteration
            iPosition = iPosition + 0.1
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
        End While   

        .Close()
  End With

  End Sub
End Module
```